# Why is my JavaScript not working in sublime text

Tags: javascript, html

Using sublime text 3, javascript won't work in browsers, to work my hamburger/toggle menu.
script5009 error occurs $ not defined

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.CSS">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="/JS/stuff.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
    <header>
 <div class="container">

  <h1 class="Logo"><img src="images/image.png"></h1>

  <nav class="site-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="">staff</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>

  <div class="menu-toggle">
    <div class="hamburger"></div>
  </div>

</div>

</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't have the jQuery script. Add this tag to the top of the file:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

And it will work.

## EDIT:

Add this code to your HTML to toggle the hamburger:

```
$(".menu-toggle").on("click", () => {
    $(".hamburger").toggle();
});
```

And it'll work.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.CSS">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/JS/stuff.js"></script>
</head>
<body> this is where I have put the code you have given me, I've got stuff.js file saved on sublime text 3. still wont carry out the javascript function, toggle box wont open and close

Comment: keeps saying html 1300 navigation occurred in browser as well

Comment: @Alan545 there's no click event handler on your menu

Comment: Jack kind of new to this and god knows I owe you a big fat sloppy kiss, since you're the only one replying, but what do you mean no click event handler?

Comment: @Alan545 I'll edit my answer with the thing you need

Comment: @Alan545 I've edited my answer, is it any better? Even if it is not, I have identified the original problem (missing jQuery), so would you mind accepting my answer?

Comment: hmmmm still not working is my code above spot on I have my javascript code in a  javascript file ive connected via <script src "/JS/stuff.js">. do I copy and paste that code you edited into the java file? I wonder if its my css code messing with it or sublime text. at this rate i'll post my laptop to ya haha

Comment: Copy/paste the code into a `<script>` element ON the HTML page, and just for now comment out your CSS link.

Comment: Hey Jack figured it out at last and yes the jquery thing I defo needed, cheers for the help mate, much love for ya x

Comment: @Alan545 Since my answer fixed your problem, would you mind accepting it by clicking the grey tick mark to the left of my answer?

Comment: @Alan545 No problem whatsoever